# Simplify logical expression represented as binary tree

Tags: binary-trees, propositional-logic

I implemented logical expressions using a binary tree in C++. Now I want to be able to simplify such an expression using rules like e.g.

[image]

but have issues with the commutativity. Assuming the expression is

[image]

then the tree would look like this:

```
       xor
       /\
     xor b
     /\
   xor true
   /\
true a
```

The expression can be simplified:

[image]

but I don't know how to apply the above rule to this tree since it is never directly applicable to one of the subtrees. Is there a better way than having to rotate the tree in all possible orders?

Comment: Convert to list, sort (so that the same variables/values are grouped together), apply rules, convert back to binary tree.

Comment: @Dmitry There's no need to sort, using a hashmap you can do it in $O(n)$ by only keeping track of the parity of each element.

Comment: @twinrix another idea is to allow ($\lnot a$) in your tree. That way you could use the reduction $true \oplus x = x \oplus true = \lnot x$ ( and ofc $false \oplus x = x$). You would end up with:
xor(true, a) => not(a),  
xor(not(a),true) => a,  
xor(a,b) as final result.
Other rules are $x\oplus \lnot x = true$,  $x \oplus x = false$.